# How to copy Youtube text by using pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(x=100,y=100,duration=10)

keyDown = ('cntrl')

pyautogui.press('c')
```

> step 1 :#importing pyautogui module.
> step 2:#moving mouse to the youtube text i want to copy
> step 3:#pressing control to copy the text
> step 4:#pressing c to copy the text.
> In simple words I dont want to do my work of copying youtube title to text file,I wanna automate it,cause its work from free intership.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try double clicking the text or drag selecting it before ctrl-c.

Also, the pyautogui documentation uses "ctrl" and not "cntrl."

```
import pyautogui

ytx = 100
yty = 100

npx = 600
npy = 100

pyautogui.moveTo(x=ytx,y=yty,duration=2)

pyautogui.doubleClick()

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

pyautogui.moveTo(x=npx,y=npy,duration=2)

pyautogui.click()

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Comment: can i get code for copying youtube title into a text file?

Comment: Not too experienced on how to automate text copying into a text file. So the only solution I can think of is opening a notepad window and adding more code lines to paste the text into that. I can write the code for that if you want me to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pyperclip` for the pasting, it's simpler. Also, use the `locateOnScreen` function, ([from here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions)) since it's more reliable than moving the mouse. Here's some pseudocode for you:

```
from pyautogui import locateOnScreen, moveTo, hotkey, ImageNotFoundException
from pyperclip import paste
try:
    # Move to top left of bar, then move into bar
    moveTo(locateOnScreen('image_of_search_bar_top_left_only.png'))
    moveRel(7, -7)
    hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as fyl:
        fyl.write(str(paste()), '\n')
except ImageNotFoundException:
    print("Unable to find search bar!")
```

Would this work for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to get text from a page, I strongly recommend looking into `pytesseract`'s image to text conversion.

It's super easy, here is an example of how it's used combining `PyAutoGui` and `Tesseract OCR`

Here I am just trying to get the string from a screenshot from a specific region on the screen.

```
#Looking for the part on the screen I want to convert, you can predefine this.
findCount = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join(curPath, 'asset', 'control.png'), confidence=0.9)

#Finding center of the area located
control_ = pyautogui.center(findCount)

#Taking a screenshot, the OS.path is just setting the path of the director, you can use an absolute path, I am then creating the region from the center of the located image.
pyautogui.screenshot(os.path.join(curPath, 'asset', 'controlValue.png'), region=(int(int(control_[0])-80), int(int(control_[1])-40), 200, 70))

#I am now opening the image
img = Image.open(os.path.join(curPath, 'asset', 'controlValue.png'))

#Converting the image to string
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

#Printing results
print(result)
```

Here is a link to the windows pytesseract installer and the OCR executable:

https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

Also at the top of your code, you need to define the OCR executable in order for this to work:

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"$Your installation path from the UB-Mannheim installer, or whereever tesseract.exe is installed."`